# Why can't we have generic methods inside non-generic classes?

Tags: c#, java, generics

In C# the following is valid:

```
public class X {
    public void F<T>(T t) {}
}
```

and do:

```
var x = new X();
x.F(2);
```

and that's not possible in Java.

I know generics work different in both languages, but I'm still wondering...

**Is there a good reason for that?**

Comment: We can. Your syntax is incorrect, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is different:

```
public class X {
    public <T> void F(T t) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @MattRS and @Kal were correctly too (both upvoted too), but you were the first :)

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I think we shouldn't encourage posting answers (and questions) that already exist.

Comment: Agreed. See the question I asked some time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/why-duplicate-an-answer

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know you CAN have generic methods inside non-generic classes in Java.

It would look like this --

```
public class Test {

        public <T> void func(T t) {
    // do something.
            }
}
```

When do you call it, test.func(2) , the 2 gets autoboxed into an Integer object

EDIT : To answer your question, whatever you are asking is exactly possible in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can, just move your generic declaration.

```
public <T> void F(T t){}
```